# Add <div> elements to arrays in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a react tutorial which implements a tic-tac-toe game. The board is rendered using a hard-coded list of `<div>`s, like so:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>        
        <div className="board-row">
          {this._renderSquare(0)}
          {this._renderSquare(1)}
          {this._renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this._renderSquare(3)}
          {this._renderSquare(4)}
          {this._renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this._renderSquare(6)}
          {this._renderSquare(7)}
          {this._renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I'm trying to convert it to using two for loops instead of hard-coding the squares. Here's what I have. `this.state.rows` and `this.state.columns` are both 3, set in the `constructor()`.

```
  render() {    
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.rows; i++) {
      rows.push(<div className="board-row">);
      for (var j = 0; j < this.state.columns; j++) {
        rows.push(this._renderSquare(i + j))
      }
      rows.push(</div>)           
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {rows}
      </div>     
    )
  }
```

Codepen is complaining about an `unexpected token` in the inner for loop of this code. However, if I comment out the lines which `push` the `board-row` div into `rows`, it works fine (but then renders as a single line of 9 boxes).

What am I doing wrong? Can't `<div>` elements be stored in arrays? Looking at some [React JSX documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components), I see that they have a `<div>` stored in a `var`, so I'm not sure what I'm doing differently.

[Complete codepen](http://codepen.io/rbd/pen/jrqjeV?editors=0010) is here: http://codepen.io/rbd/pen/jrqjeV?editors=0010

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`rows.push(<div className="board-row">);` is not legal JSX. Keep in mind what JSX actually transpiles to:

Consider `var Foo = <div className="board-row" />`. (self closing)

This will turn into:

```
var Foo = React.createElement("div", { className: "board-row" })
```

If you have children in your jsx:

```
var Foo =
  <div className="board-row">
    <span />
  <div>
```

It will turn into this: (third argument is children)

```
var Foo = React.createElement("div", { className: "board-row" },
  React.createElement("span")
)
```

So there really is no such thing as calling `createElement` with just an opening or just closing tags.

That being said you could rewrite your loop such that the inner loop is adding child nodes. Also the `_renderSquare` function is expecting increasing numbers from 0 - 8. You had `i + j`, but this isn't the right equation as that way you will get `0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4`.

```
var rows = [];
var cells = [];
var cellNumber = 0; <-- keep track of increasing value
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.rows; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < this.state.columns; j++) {
    cells.push(this._renderSquare(cellNumber))
    cellNumber++
  }
  rows.push(<div className="board-row">{ cells }</div>)
  cells = [];
}
```

It will complain about adding a missing `key` prop, so always make sure to do that when creating elements in a loop. You will need to do that here in your `div` and in your `_renderSquare` function on the `Square`. Using the `index` as the key should be fine in this case.

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/qNaRdr?editors=0010)**

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to not only offer the solution, but also explain what's going on under the hood.

Comment: `(i*3) + j` will give you the cell number without an extra variable.

Answer (score -4):

I can see that part of the problem is you are missing quotes on your push methods.

```
rows.push(<div className="board-row">);
```

should be

```
rows.push('<div className="board-row">');
```

and

```
rows.push(</div>)
```

should be

```
rows.push('</div>');
```

Comment: jsx does not use quotes

Comment: Yup, to add to what @azium said: using quotes would push a string to the array, which is not what I want.